# How to configure spring boot with mysql and elasticsearch

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa, spring-boot

I am writing a POC on Spring boot, mysql JPA and ElasticSearch. I am configuring all those thing which required for configuration. Now I am able to perform the CRUD operation with elasticsearch, mysql also create the table but not save the value. How will I resolve the issue.

here is my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>com.github.vanroy</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jest</artifactId>
          <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

application.properties file:

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.path.home=target/elastic
spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.transport.tcp.connect_timeout=120s
spring.data.jest.uri=http://localhost:9200
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employeedb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

I have also created two repository and using the annotation

```
@SpringBootApplication(
    scanBasePackages={"com.example"}, 
    exclude = {ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.class, ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages ="com.example.jpa")
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you are adding properties which are using in auto configuration, disable the auto configuration and still expect it to work... You have configured things manually so you aren't relying on Spring Boot for that. So add that modified configuration.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Finally I get the solution

Comment: Hey @Kumar , would you please share the solution ?? I am in exact situation where you were at... TIA

Comment: @Kumar - Kindly share the solution as it will help others with the same issue as me.